# Flutter Firebase Realtime Database MissingPluginException

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to add user data to my Realtime Database like this:

```
submitForm(String username, String email, String password) async {
    final auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    UserCredential userCredential;
    try {
      if (_isLoginPage) {
        userCredential = await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: email, password: password);
      } else {
        userCredential = await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: email, password: password);
        String uid = userCredential.user.uid;
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(uid).set({
          'username': username,
          'email': email,
        });
        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref('users');
        await ref.push().set({
          'username': username,
          'email': email,
        }).asStream();
      }
    } catch (err) {
      print('zort');
      print(err);
    }
  }
```

Adding the data to Firestore and Firebase Auth works perfectly but I get this error on the Realtime Database step:
`MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method DatabaseReference#set on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_database)`

I tried all the usual stuff like `flutter pub get` and `flutter clean` but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Please try to upgrade flutter with link https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/sdk/upgrading and try again also you can refer the stackoverflow link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59296853/flutter-cloud-firestore-missingpluginexception-exception

Answer (score 0):

Posting above comment in the answer section,

Can you please try to upgrade flutter with [link](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/sdk/upgrading) and try again also you can refer the [stackoverflow URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59296853/flutter-cloud-firestore-missingpluginexception-exception)